# how to hide resource for particular user in filament?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I'm trying to create a website that have two interface one for admin and other for users. So, for that I want that the resource panel in navigation bar/sidebar was visible to only admin/id==1, Resources like studentresource. Detail like Users login i don't want to show  to all users that who was login.

I'm expecting to hide the resources panel for all users except id==1/admin or create two whole panel the one panel for user  and other for admin.

Comment: Sounds like should be easily do-able with standard role-based access controls. Without seeing more detail it's difficult to give more specific advice. See [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. It's unclear where/how you're stuck exactly with achieving this.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static function canViewAny(): bool
    {
        return auth()->user()->id==1;
    }
```

Use this in your resource